# Comparing values and keys of two objects

Tags: javascript, object

Good day, all.

I've got

```
Object A = {
  "a" : "3.1.2",
  "b" : "4.1.1",
  "c" : "3.0.0",
  "y" : "5.0.0"
}

Object B = {
  "a" : "^3.1.2",
  "t" : "^4.1.1",
  "c" : "~2.2.2"
}
```

How I could check that does the Object B get the same key as in Object A?
`If the key in Object A === key in Object B`, check the value of that key.
If the value of that key the same don't do anything.
If the value from `Object A !=== value in Object B`, push it to the Array in the next example `["c@3.0.0"]`
If the `key in Object A` doesn't exist in `Object B` immediately push key and value from Object A to the same array `["c@3.0.0", "y@5.0.0"]`

Comment: Your efforts so far ? code you've tried so far ?

Comment: I could understand how it could be with key or only with value. But I didn't understand how to do what I write about.

Comment: You can first check for `key` existence and than inside same if compare the `values`

Comment: Let me check, try it now.

Comment: Are you supposed to ignore the `^` and `~` characters in object B?

Comment: Yeap, I understand how to do this. By using .replace(/[`~^]/gi, '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to do it.

Iterate on the entries of the object A, for each entry, check if there is an entry in B. If there is not, push the value to the array. If there is an entry and the version numbers are the same, do nothing, otherwise, push it to the array too.

To compare the version numbers, you can use a regex (`/^\^|~/`) to remove the first `^` or `~` before comparing the values.

```js
const A = {
  "a" : "3.1.2",
  "b" : "4.1.1",
  "c" : "3.0.0",
  "y" : "5.0.0"
};

const B = {
  "a" : "^3.1.2",
  "t" : "^4.1.1",
  "c" : "~2.2.2"
};

const result = Object.entries(A).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
  const bEntry = B[key] && B[key].replace(/^\^|~/, '');
  return bEntry !== val ? [...acc, `${key}@${val}`] : acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```